# How do I access static variables within a class without class names in PHP?

Tags: php, static-variables

Is there any way to access a static variable of a PHP class without using the class prefix?

Example:

```
class A {

   protected static $x = "blahblah";

   public static function p() {

       print(A::$x); // <= Is there no way to omit A:: ???

   }

}
```

I understand, that at that point $x could be an uninitialized local variable, but it would make a lot of sense to be able to say/declare/set that in these cases the interpreter should resolve $x as the member declared earlier. Typing the class prefix everywhere is a major fail IMHO.

Comment: self::$x works from within the class

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the method you're using it from is in the same class, you can use self:: or static::.

E.g.:

```
class A {

   protected static $x = "blahblah";

   public static function p() {

       print(self::$x);

   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however my point was to skip typing the prefix every time... :)

Comment: Well, self:: and static:: save you from having to refactor every reference to the variable inside the class if you ever change the class's name, but I don't think there's a way to reference static variables without specifying the class in some way (be it the class's name or self:: or static::).